# Updating control in frmMain from an Async sub in another Class

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to update a textbox (LiveLog) on frmMain from another class.

If frmMain I have added:

```
Public contextlogupdater As SynchronizationContext = SynchronizationContext.Current

Dim lastlogdate As String = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")

Public Sub UpdateLiveLog(logtext As Object)
     Me.txtLiveLog.Text = Me.txtLiveLog.Text & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & logtext
     Me.Refresh()
    End Sub
```

And in the other class I have added:

```
Public Class Monitoring
   TestingLog()
   
   Private Sub TestingLog()
      frmMain.contextlogupdater.Post(AddressOf frmMain.UpdateLiveLog, "Some text for the log")
      StartReceivedListener()
   End Sub
   Private Async Function StartReceivedListener() As Task
      ReceivedTimer = New Timers.Timer(60000)
      ReceivedTimer.AutoReset = True
      AddHandler ReceivedTimer.Elapsed, AddressOf CollectReceivedMail
      ReceivedTimer.Start()
   End Function
   Private Async Sub CollectReceivedMail(ByVal source As Object, ByVal e As Timers.ElapsedEventArgs)
      frmMain.contextlogupdater.Post(AddressOf frmMain.UpdateLiveLog, "Some other text for the log")
   End Sub
End Class
```

The first text (some text for the log) gets sent to the textbox on frmMain, but the second (Some other text for the log) doesn't. What am I doing wrong?

I's appreciate any helpful suggestions or solutions.

---

I tried adding an event as suggested so I have:

In frmMain

```
Public WithEvents mMonitor As MailMonitor

Private Sub frmMain_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        mMonitor = New MailMonitor
End Sub

Private Sub mMonitor_Elogupdate(logtext As String) Handles mMonitor.Elogupdate
        txtLiveLog.Text = logtext
        Refresh()
End Sub
```

and in the other class (MailMonitor) I have:

```
Public Event Elogupdate(logtext As String)

Private Sub StartMonitoring()
        RaiseEvent Elogupdate("Starting SMTP Client")
        StartSentListener()
End Sub
```

I'm obviously still doing something wrong?

Comment: I'd use a `BackgroundWorker`, that's what it's for.

Comment: While it could use a lot of improvement in following conventions, your new code looks like it should work as is. You haven't explained the actual issue with the code so it's hard to say for sure what the issue might but one glaring omission from what you posted is a call to the `StartMonitoring` method. Of course nothing will happen if you don't call that method but maybe you're calling it somewhere that you haven't shown us. Regardless, you need to actually explain your issue. Just code is not an explanation. What EXACTLY do you expect to happen and what does happen? Debug your code.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The OP describes what I expect to happen: the text "starting SMTP client" should be passed to frmMain and update the textbox txtLiveLog on that form. What happens is that the code raises the event (ie the code steps through the line RaiseEvenet......but doesnt pass the text to frmMain.

Answer (score 0):

Your `CollectReceivedMail` method is being executed on a different thread. You are referring to the default instance of `frmMain` but default instances are thread-specific, so you're probably referring to a different instance to the one you're looking at on screen. Read more about default instances [here](https://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com/2009/07/vbnet-default-form-instances.html).

The best solution is to not do this the dodgy beginner way, i.e. accessing the form and its contents directly from the other class, but rather do it the proper way, where the other class doesn't even know that the form exists. You should raise an event in that other class and the form should handle that event. Any data required can be passed via the event or exposed via properties for the form to get when the event is raised. The form then does everything that needs to be done internally. Read more about raising your own events [here](https://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com/2009/11/defining-and-raising-custom-events.html).

Having said that, you can still make it work with similar code to what you have now. The problem is that you are misusing the `SynchronizationContext`. There is no poi8nt of reason to use a `SynchronizationContext` in a form. The form already implements the `ISychronizeInvoke` interface, so it can already sync across threads. The point of the `SynchronizationContext` is to provide similar functionality in classes that don't already have it. You should be using a `SynchronizationContext` inside `Monitoring`, not inside `frmMain`. The idea is that, when you create an instance of `Monitoring` on the UI thread, it gets the current `SynchronizationContext` and it can then use that on other threads to sync. You sync inside the `Monitoring` class first to get to the UI thread, then you can use the default instance of `frmMain` without issue.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have updated my question with the code for using events.